# Why is dynamic allocation not required here

Tags: c, dynamic

Why is dynamic allocation not required in this code?

```
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)

{
   int i, w;
   int K[n+1][W+1];

   // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
   for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
   {
       for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
       {
           if (i==0 || w==0)
               K[i][w] = 0;
           else if (wt[i-1] <= w)
                 K[i][w] = max(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]],  K[i-1][w]);
           else
                 K[i][w] = K[i-1][w];
       }
   }

   return K[n][W];
}
```

I always felt I could not declare array with size of a variable such as `K[n+1][W+1];`

Comment: It's a VLA which C99 added support for.

Comment: It's a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), a C99 addition.

Comment: ...and then pray that no one passes in some large value for `W` or `n`.  I would avoid them altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a C99 feature. It is dynamically allocating on the stack for you.

Here's an explanation of variable-length arrays work in GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html